# Bootstrap 4 pills on navbar disappears on click

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I am attempting to add bootstrap 4 pills to my navbar for a rails 5 app, along with a scroll spy. For the most part, this seems to work. However, on the second click, the pills disappear. For example, clicking on one of the links, say about, works fine, but then clicking on a second link, say features, fails.

Here is the code for my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item active" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#one">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#two">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#three">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#four">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and the code in my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not have any custom javascript (maybe that's the problem?), and the console output doesn't show any errors (Here I've started the server, then clicked About, then clicked Contact Us, and on the Contact Us click, the pills disappear):

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-26 09:55:35 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-26 09:55:35 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 326ms (Views: 324.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Completed 200 OK in 543ms (Views: 535.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-26 09:55:37 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 54.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-26 09:55:39 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 51.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**EDIT:** In playing around with this, I've noticed that on the second click of a nav link, there's a slight flicker followed by the pills disappearing.
Any idea why this is happening?
Thank you!

Comment: any custom javascript code that you have? any console outputs?

Comment: I don't have any javascript written, and I've posted an example console output. Unfortunately, the console output doesn't indicate any errors occuring